# Scroll to every span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html structure

`.honors` is set to `overflow: auto` and fix height.

How can i do it to make it scroll to every  element

```
<div class="honors">

 <p><span class="title-red t1">Title1</span content ...</p>
 <p><span class="title-red t2">Title2</span content ...</p>
 <p><span class="title-red t3">Title3</span content ...</p>
 <p><span class="title-red t4">Title4</span content ...</p>

</div>

<a id="scrollUp" href="#">up</a>
<a id="scrollDown" href="#">down</a>
```

Here's my jquery code

```
    jQuery(function($) {
    var step = 50;
    $("#scrollUp").on("click", function (event) {
        // Animates the scrollTop property by the specified
        // step.
        $(".honors").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        },2000);

         event.preventDefault();
    })


    $("#scrollDown").on("click", function (event) {
        $(".honors").animate({
            scrollTop: "+=" + step + "px"           
        }, 500);
         event.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll to *every* element"? The page can have only one position at a time.

Comment: what i mean is if i click the down button link it will scroll to first span element then to the next span when i click the button again and so on...

Comment: did u mean u need to move up and down ??

Comment: scroll top is okay, just the scroll down. my code in scroll down is wrong as it didn't move to every <span> as i click down button everytime.

Comment: you know you can do it with p elements...

Comment: yes i'm thinking also to that rather than the span elements. But i don't know how to achieve that..

Comment: It is working fine only.http://jsfiddle.net/jhCGQ/.or expecting some other functionality from this??

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery.scrollTo, to scroll to a specific element like so:

```
var nextElem;
$("#scrollDown").on("click", function (event) {
    if (nextElem === undefined) {

        nextElem = $('.title-red').next();
    } else {

        nextElem = nextElem.next();
    }
    $(".honors").scrollTo(nextElem, 800, {
        margin: true
    });
    event.preventDefault();
})
})
```

Fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VLsU/)

Dont forget to include the scrollTo Plugin. Also you have to adjust the #scrollTop method because all it's curently doing is scrolling to the first Element.

Comment: thanks gulty this is what i'm looking for. About the scroll top i'm thinking of using .scrollTo on it now. How can i make it scroll to top on every previous .title-red element?